# SQL Help Required - query contains all users added the previous day

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE creationDate >= GetDate() -1 AND creationDate < GetDate()
```

Could you please let me know How do I get the result for

> Report contains all users added the previous day

Here I want to know make the `WHERE` clause on "creationDate" column on yesterday date, e.g.:

`DD:MM:YYYY:12:01:00 (AM)` and `DD:MM:YYYY:11:59:00 (PM)`.

I am new to SQL, please help me.

Comment: Sir, This is my query SELECT  *
FROM    TableName
WHERE   creationDate >= GaetDate() -1 AND
        creationDate < GaetDate()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get all records from the previous day, you can do something like this with the `dateadd` and `datediff` functions:

```
SELECT users 
FROM "yourTable"
WHERE Createddate >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
    AND Createddate < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

If you have **date range**  you can do it using the `between` function:

```
SELECT users FROM "yourTable"
WHERE Createddate between "yourFirstDate" and "yourSecondDate"
```

Or you can do it like this:

```
SELECT users FROM "yourTable"
WHERE Createddate = "yourDate"
```

Comment: The second one will probably fail. Cast it to `DATE`

Comment: Thanks sir, for your response. As I have mentioned in my query as such I don't have from date and to date , We have to get the through query, I have only CreateDate column in my Table which has all the values like : 25:06:2016:00:10:000,25:06:2016:01:18:000,25:06:2016:06:10:000,25:06:2016:22:10:000,25:06:2016:23:27:000.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick help , My issue got resolved.

Answer (score -1):

A more optimized method:

```
SELECT
    users 
FROM
    yourTable
WHERE
    Createddate >= cast(floor(cast(dateadd(day,-1,getdate())as float))as datetime)
AND
    Createddate < cast(ceiling(cast(dateadd(day,-1,getdate())as float))as datetime)
```